# WCF Client cant read "mutlipart/reoated"

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a simpel WCF-Client.

**Binding**

```
var binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport);
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
```

So now my Problem. The server respond with somthing like this:

```
--MIMEBoundary_4c0931c2662c48df1de58a689b82ce1eb3373535d903393a
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <0.5c0931c2662c48df1de58a689b82ce1eb3373535d903393a@apache.org>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<--rest of the response xml-->
--MIMEBoundary_4c0931c2662c48df1de58a689b82ce1eb3373535d903393a--
```

It looks like the normal respond is simply packed in the MIMEBoundary. I try to switch to MTOM. But i got this Error:

> Error creating a reader for the MTOM message.
>
> MTOM messages must have type 'application/xop+xml'

What could i do?

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: Yes i use: http://wcfswaencoder.codeplex.com/ with some small tweaks for my projekt (switch to Soap11WSAddressing10, set ContentType to PDF, allows SwA without an attachments) . But 99% off the job does this lib :)